# What's wrong with my brainfuck parser code?

Tags: java, parsing, brainfuck, esoteric-languages

I'm trying to make a program in Java that can read, compile, and run [brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) source files (`.bf`). I've gotten it to work just fine with Wikipedia's Hello World example, but it breaks on the ROT13 example (claims it reached an unmatched `]` when it was actually matched).

The actual parser code is all written in one `.JAVA` file, but the heart of it (the actual brainfuck parser and running code) is in the below method, `doNow(char)`. Here are what the variables are: `cells` is the array of characters to be run (`char[]`); `pointer` is the Java workaround to point to an address in the array (`short`); `PC` is the program counter (`int`), and `loopStack` is a stack of addresses which correspond to `[`s (basically a `short[]`). These are not the problem, as they work just fine in the Hello World test. The method that takes input automatically filters out excess characters, and I confirmed it to work perfectly from debug inspection.

**Why doesn't this parser run the ROT 13 code?**

### Code

---

**My parser, written in Java**

```
  /** The array of data */
  private byte[] cells = new byte[Short.MAX_VALUE];
  /** The pointer that is manipulated by the user or program */
  private short pointer = 0;
  /** The program counter, to run compiled programs */
  private int PC = 0;
  /** The compiled commands */
  private ArrayPP<Character> commandBuffer = new ArrayPP<>();
  /** The stack of locations of loop brackets ({@code [}) in the command buffer */
  private ArrayPP<Short> loopStack = new ArrayPP<>();//ArrayPP is my proprietary augmented array object, which also functions as a perfectly working stack.

  public int doNow(char command) throws IOException
  {
    PC++;
    switch (command)
    {
      case '>':
        return ++pointer;
      case '<':
        return --pointer;
      case '+':
        return ++cells[pointer];
      case '-':
        return --cells[pointer];
      case '.':
        System.out.print((char)cells[pointer]);
        return 0;
      case ',':
        return cells[pointer] = (byte)System.in.read();
      case '[':
        if (cells[pointer] == 0)//If we're ready to skip this conditional
        {
          int oldPC = PC;
          try
          {
            while (getCompiledCommand(PC) != ']')//Find the matching ]
              PC++;
            PC++;//Now that we're at the ], skip over it to the next command
          }
          catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
          {
            throw new NullPointerException("Unmatched '[' at " + oldPC);//If we try to reference a command outside the buffer
          }
        }
        else//if we want to enter this conditional
          loopStack.push(PC - 1);//Add the location of this conditional to the list of conditionals which we are in
        return PC;
      case ']':
        try
        {
          return PC = loopStack.pop();//Move us to the matching [ and remove it from the list of conditionals we're in
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
          throw new NullPointerException("Unmatched ] at " + PC);//If the loop stack is empty
        }
      default:
        throw new AssertionError(command + " is not a valid command.");
    }
  }
  public char getCompiledCommand(int commandIndex)
  {
    return commandBuffer.get(commandIndex);//Look into the buffer of precompiled commands and fetch the one at the given index
  }
```

**The Hello World example** (works perfectly)

```
+++++ +++++             initialize counter (cell #0) to 10
[                       use loop to set the next four cells to 70/100/30/10
    > +++++ ++              add  7 to cell #1
    > +++++ +++++           add 10 to cell #2 
    > +++                   add  3 to cell #3
    > +                     add  1 to cell #4
    <<<< -                  decrement counter (cell #0)
]                   
> ++ .                  print 'H'
> + .                   print 'e'
+++++ ++ .              print 'l'
.                       print 'l'
+++ .                   print 'o'
> ++ .                  print ' '
<< +++++ +++++ +++++ .  print 'W'
> .                     print 'o'
+++ .                   print 'r'
----- - .               print 'l'
----- --- .             print 'd'
> + .                   print '!'
> .                     print '\n'
```

**ROT 13 example** (My test console input is `M`. Breaks on command 54 after several loop iterations)

```
-,+[                         Read first character and start outer character reading loop
    -[                       Skip forward if character is 0
        >>++++[>++++++++<-]  Set up divisor (32) for division loop
                               (MEMORY LAYOUT: dividend copy remainder divisor quotient zero zero)
        <+<-[                Set up dividend (x minus 1) and enter division loop
            >+>+>-[>>>]      Increase copy and remainder / reduce divisor / Normal case: skip forward
            <[[>+<-]>>+>]    Special case: move remainder back to divisor and increase quotient
            <<<<<-           Decrement dividend
        ]                    End division loop
    ]>>>[-]+                 End skip loop; zero former divisor and reuse space for a flag
    >--[-[<->+++[-]]]<[         Zero that flag unless quotient was 2 or 3; zero quotient; check flag
        ++++++++++++<[       If flag then set up divisor (13) for second division loop
                               (MEMORY LAYOUT: zero copy dividend divisor remainder quotient zero zero)
            >-[>+>>]         Reduce divisor; Normal case: increase remainder
            >[+[<+>-]>+>>]   Special case: increase remainder / move it back to divisor / increase quotient
            <<<<<-           Decrease dividend
        ]                    End division loop
        >>[<+>-]             Add remainder back to divisor to get a useful 13
        >[                   Skip forward if quotient was 0
            -[               Decrement quotient and skip forward if quotient was 1
                -<<[-]>>     Zero quotient and divisor if quotient was 2
            ]<<[<<->>-]>>    Zero divisor and subtract 13 from copy if quotient was 1
        ]<<[<<+>>-]          Zero divisor and add 13 to copy if quotient was 0
    ]                        End outer skip loop (jump to here if ((character minus 1)/32) was not 2 or 3)
    <[-]                     Clear remainder from first division if second division was skipped
    <.[-]                    Output ROT13ed character from copy and clear it
    <-,+                     Read next character
]                            End character reading loop
```

to make it clear, here's where it breaks:

```
            >[+[<+>-]>+>>]   Special case: increase remainder / move it back to divisor / increase quotient
                         ^
```

Comment: @defaultlocale What's wrong? Too long? Did you want the declarations of the Java variables? That shouldn't matter; the problem is with the posted method. I'll add them for you, though.

Comment: is `getCompiledCommand()` aware of nested '['-']'? If so, when you see '[', you go forward to the very first ']', which is wrong for, e.g `[+++[----]+]` - the first '[' is matched with the first ']'. Your 'Hello world' contains just a single pair, that's why it works.

Comment: @Supuhstar, nothing is actually wrong. I hope someone will manage to help you. But if readers are able to run your code it will be a lot easier to find a problem.

Comment: oh, yeah. sorry. `getCompiledCommand(int)` simply returns a character that's been loaded into memory from a file or other text input source. It isn't aware of anything, nor does it have conditional logic. Though, I see your point. Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Supuhstar, also I think you should output and include exception details. Stack trace, in particular.

Comment: @Supuhstar Sure, already done :)

Comment: @defaultlocale the Java stack trace is very uninformative. It is a simple `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Unmatched ] at 54
 at bf.BFParser.doNow(BFParser.java:207)`

There is no BF Stack trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should keep track of '[]' nestedness in the '[' case branch: now, the match for the first '[' in `[+++[----]+]` is the first ']', which is not good.

Comment: Yeah, I actually caught this just before you posted your comment pointing it out. I'll still accept yours as an answer, but I posted my solution, as well :3

Answer (score 4):

### Problem

---

It seems the problem lies in this line:

```
            while (getCompiledCommand(PC) != ']')//Find the matching ]
```

This works fine  in the Hello World program because it has no nested loops. However, with nested loops, we run into the problem that it hits the first encountered `]`, which is not always the matching `]`.

### Fix

---

One possible fix is to introduce a variable before the while loop, say `loopCount`, and increment it every time a `[` is encountered, then decrement it when a `]` is encountered and `loopCount` is greater than 0. For instance:

```
        int loopCount = 0;
        while ((command = getCompiledCommand(PC)) != ']' && loopCount == 0)//Find the matching ]. We can save the return in command because we're done using it.
        {
          if (command == '[')//If we run into a nested loop
            loopCount++;
          else if (command == ']')//If we run into the end of a nested loop
            loopCount--;

          PC++;
        }
```